# Firebase concurrent lock/unlock write access multiple device

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm looking some tip about how to lock/unlock write access of firebase in concurrent access from multiple device for android

I would like to be able to do something like this:

- get write access and lock
- runnable process -> get some data from firebase, process it
- runnable process -> get back data from previous runnable, write some data to firebase
- runnable process -> get back data from another runnable, get another data, process them
- runnable process -> write some data
- and so and so
- task execute all synchronous runnable, write bunch of data to firebase
- unlock write access

My first idea, is to add to timeout. The lock write can expire alone if you don't unlock before the giving allowed amount to ensure no device can block the access.

I read about Transaction, but I don't think it suit my demand. Because I need access to multiple path while processing.

In anyone has any idea how to implement a lock/unlock write access which a device should acquire before to be able to write ?

Thanks for any idea.

PS: my runnable synchronous task do already perfectly the job, I'm just looking how to lock and unlock write access of firebase to be sure no other device can corrupt the data while I processing some.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Realtime Database nor Cloud Firestore have a mechanism where you can force a lock of the entire database, or even just a part of it, for an arbitrary amount of time while you do work on it.  Something like this simply wouldn't scale in the real world.

Both databases provide a transaction mechanism, which is the only way to perform reads and writes atomically and consistently.  If you have absolute requirements for some other form of locking, a cloud-hosted database might not be your best option.  Either that, or you funnel all access through a single piece of middleware that you control, which also will not scale well.

Comment: Of course there is, lock for maintenance, isn't a lock of entire database? ... Why wouldn't scale in real world, do you have all universe anwser ?  i'm agree with the transaction but transaction of firebase is not multipath. so no usefull in my case.

Comment: Firebase databases don't have any hard locking mechanism exposed to the developer.  They can lead to deadlock if used incorrectly, and cause throughput problems when under high load.  If you need a hard locking mechanism, consider a different database.

Comment: " if used incorrectly" so developer are children? Just commercial way to explain you don't have these features because it is for your safety. lol. So i just have to build something to achieve to lock mechanisme.

Comment: There are a lot of different databases out there that solve different problems and use cases. It sounds like you'd be helped by choosing a different one that meets your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way

Here how todo:

- use transaction
- read an entry at the path you want and lock the path you want, Entry is guid + timestamp of your device.
- if the timestamp < than your, the path is no lock, you can take it by writing your guid and your timestamp + the time your require the lock.
- when the transaction is sucesful, your are the winner and can do whatever you want.
- when finish, write the current timestamp to free the lock

Answer (score 1):

If someone need it, here is how I did to buidl and acquire one lock at specifique path 3s.
- At each table (path), you can associate one tableInfo which contain the lock for this path.
- then acquire, release and extend the time if no one else need the lock. You can add a listener on another field with guid of other device which try to acquire this lock. And be nice to realease it instead of extend your time.

```
fbBase.child(tableInfoChildRef).child(TableInfo.Field.Lock.name).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                public Map<String, Object> lock(){
                    Map<String, Object> data = new ArrayMap<>();
                    data.put(TableInfo.Field.Lock.guid, AppGUID.get().toString());
                    data.put(TableInfo.Field.Lock.timestamp, System.currentTimeMillis()+3000);
                    return data;
                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public Transaction.Result doTransaction(@NonNull MutableData mutableData) {

                    if(mutableData.getValue() == null) {
                        mutableData.setValue(lock());
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }else{
                        Long lockTimestamp = mutableData.child(TableInfo.Field.Lock.timestamp).getValue(Long.class);
                        if(lockTimestamp < System.currentTimeMillis()){
                            mutableData.setValue(lock());
                            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                        }
                    }
                    return Transaction.abort();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, @Nullable DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(b) LogDelay.send("WIN");
                    else LogDelay.send("LOSE");
                }
            });
```